# How does spring oauth2 clientDetails.getAuthorities() help/work?

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2, spring-oauth2

I am going through this [api doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/ClientDetails.html#getAuthorities()) ([source](https://github.com/spring-attic/spring-security-oauth/blob/main/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/ClientDetails.java#L86)) of Spring OAuth2 ClientDetails Interface.  And I am not sure how this i.e `clientDetails.getAuthorities()` works or helps in the authorization flow. The API docs describes it as below:

```
Collection<org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities()

Returns the authorities that are granted to the OAuth client. Cannot return null. Note that these are NOT the authorities that are granted to the user with an authorized access token. Instead, these authorities are inherent to the client itself.

Returns:
    the authorities (never null)
```

And I understand the above is different from the `userDetails.getAuthorities()` of [UserDetails](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/main/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetails.java#L49) Interface. The API docs says as below:

```
java.util.Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities()

Returns the authorities granted to the user. Cannot return null.

Returns:
    the authorities, sorted by natural key (never null)
```

I understand that, in ClientDetails we are dealing with granting permission to the OAuth2 Client, while in UserDetails we are granting the permission to User i.e Principal.

**But how is the former different from later and when to use the former.**

---

A little elaboration -
When dealing with OAuth, we are dealing with tokens issued by Auth Server. The tokens are typically `jwt tokens` with information about the authorities granted to the **User**. A typical base64 decoded token's payload might look like below:

```
{
  "app-userId": "c54a-4140-9fa0-0f39",
  "user_name": "abc@xyz.com",
  "scope": [
    "all"
  ],
  "exp": 1656929583,
  "authorities": [
    "app1_viewer",
    "app1_modifier",
    "app2_viewer",
    "app2_blog_creator],
  "client_id": "client_A"
  ...
}
```

The `authorities` above are the authorities of the **User** who is logged-in and using the app.

1. When the user accesses app1 - it checks the above jwt token to make sure the user has the required permissions/authorities.
2. If app1 has to call app2, then app1 passes the above jwt which is specific to current user (as Authorization header) to app2. App2 processes this jwt token received in headers and checks if the user has permissions to access/edit the resource. And returns 200 or 403 accordingly.

As you can see, the process is dealing with `userDetails.getAuthorities()`.  So, how and where or in which case does `clientDetails.getAuthorities()` help. What are the use cases/examples of it.
Could some one explain. Thanks for any answers.

Comment: very well written Q. Myself too looking for some answers. Hope there will be few soon.

Comment: anyone aware about `spring framework` specific site where i can  re-ask this question. (something like https://discourse.hibernate.org/ for hibernate specific Q's.. and by the way the hibernate discourse is extremely active and helpful if anyone is looking for second forum for hibernate besides the No. 1 SOF. )

Answer (score 0):

I am not a Java hero, but I work a lot with Azure and Oauth2. Your question got me thinking what that could be. From what I learned is that Authorities decide who gets a valid token and who doesn't (token issuer). From the Microsoft Azure [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-client-application-configuration#authority) about MSAL I got the following:

> **Authority**
>
> The authority is a URL that indicates a directory that MSAL can
> request tokens from.
>
> Common authorities are:
>
> - https://login.microsoftonline.com/TENANT/
>   Sign in users of a
>   specific organization only. The  in the URL is the tenant ID
>   of the Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) tenant (a GUID), or its
>   tenant domain.
> - https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/   Sign in users
>   with work and school accounts or personal Microsoft accounts.
> - https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/    Sign in users with
>   work and school accounts.
> - https://login.microsoftonline.com/consumers/    Sign in users with
>   personal Microsoft accounts (MSA) only.

A valid use case could be that one wants to build a multi-tenant application. So users from multiple authorities are able to sign-up and sign-in to your application. On basis of the authority you can filter which data a user can see, only data from the users' organization for example. Basically the same idea as how you would use the application roles from `userDetails.getAuthorities()` to restrict what a user can see or do according to his role within that specific application.

Comment: `On basis of the authority you can filter which data a user can see, only data from the users' organization` - to address this - the auth-server needs to insert the users company_id in the users jwt token and the resource server got to ensure that the user can access only details of company that is in there signed jwt token. If they try to hack trying to access some other company details they would get 403

Comment: as there is no other competing answer.. doing +100 bounty.